# How can I list my company in Stack Overflow companies?

Tags: support, companies-page

I am aware that the jobs feature has been removed as of April 2022, but I would like to clarify if we would still be able to access the [companies listed in the relevant section](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies) for the long run.

If so, I'd like to know how can I create a page for my company and add details + team members?

Comment: Considering that that page had over 1,400 companies listed on it [a year ago](https://web.archive.org/web/20210614015436/https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies) and now only 136, I suspect that the feature is likely going the same way as jobs.

Comment: Contact their [talent department](https://stackoverflow.co/talent/solutions/#awareness) (https://stackoverflow.co/talent/contact). Obligatory note that it's a paid service (AFAIK)

Comment: ... And only the "***Best** Companies (Hiring Developers)*" get listed...!

Comment: aka the ones with the deepest pockets

Comment: But what is best? I know Conan has [a solid answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oo9buo9Mtos), but it doesn't apply to software very often.

Comment: @user4581301 hm, maybe if you consider bugs and performance problems to be your enemies... It kind of works.

Comment: @Larnu 135 now :')

Comment: Is it possible to add a company ?  It is not said if the service is allways alive, or closed...